# How to write to channel on ReadTimeoutHandler before channel closes in Netty 4

Tags: netty, netty4

The behaviour of `ReadTimeoutHandler` seems to have changed in Netty 4 compared with Netty 3. In Netty 4 when the timeout fires, Netty not only raises a `ReadTimeoutException` but also closes the channel. This was not the case before. In Netty 3, the behaviour is to only raise the `ReadTimeoutException`, the channel is not closed.

I have a use case where I need to write a message to the channel, on timeout. This can't be done anymore because by the time, the code that handles the thrown `ReadTimeoutException` is reached, the channel is already closed.

Any tips/ideas on how to go about this use case in Netty 4? Basically write to the channel on `ReadTimeoutException` before Netty closes the channel?

Comment: A working solution for now is to extend ReadTimeoutHandler and not close the channel in  the readTimedOut implementation. Would be cool to see if someone more familiar with Netty has a more idiomatic approach

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to use `IdleStateHandler` which is more flexible in how you handle different types of idle events.